# Passing three dimensional arrays to a function in C

Tags: c, arrays

I use to program with `FORTRAN`, but I decided to learn `C` and `C++`. I started with `C` language, and the one thing that I never used are pointers, because `FORTRAN` pass values by reference. I built the sample code below to understand how pointers work with multidimensional arrays:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 

#define DIM1 3
#define DIM2 2 
#define DIM3 4

void display3DArray1(int, int , int n, int (*arr)[][n]);
void display3DArray2(int rows, int cols1, int cols2,int arr[][cols1][cols2]);

int main(void)
{
    int matrix3D[DIM1][DIM2][DIM3] = {
        {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {5, 6, 7, 8}},
        {{9, 10, 11, 12}, {13, 14, 15, 16}},
        {{17, 18, 19, 20}, {21, 22, 23, 24}}
    };
    int (*pmatrix3D)[DIM2][DIM3] = matrix3D;

    display3DArray1(DIM1, DIM2, DIM3,pmatrix3D); 
    display3DArray2(DIM1, DIM2, DIM3,pmatrix3D); 

    return 0;
}

void display3DArray1(int rows, int cols1, int cols2,int (*arr)[][cols2]) {
    printf("\n");
    for(int i=0; i<rows; i++) {
        for(int j=0; j<cols1; j++) {
            for(int k=0; k<cols2; k++) {
                printf("*arr : %d adress: %p\n",*(*((*arr+i*cols1))+j*cols2+k),*((*arr+i*cols1))+j*cols2+k);
            }
        }
    }
}

void display3DArray2(int rows, int cols1, int cols2,int arr[][cols1][cols2]) {
    printf("\n");
    for(int i=0; i<rows; i++) {
        for(int j=0; j<cols1; j++) {
            for(int k=0; k<cols2; k++) {
                printf("*arr : %d adress: %p\n", *(*(*(arr+i)+j) + k), *(*(arr+i)+j) + k) ;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The code works, but there is something that I wasn't able to understand. When I try to use the second `printf` of the second function in the first one I get a compilation error:

> "invalid use of array with unspecified bounds" -- under gcc.

Why `*(arr + i)` doesn't work in the first function?

Comment: Indent your code, please..

Comment: Please don't use pointer syntax `*(arr+i)` to get array elements. Use `arr[i]` instead, it's much more clear what your intent is.

Comment: I do not get an error with gcc 5.4.0 under cygwin. Are you compiling this exact program? With which compiler, which flags? (Oh, gcc. Okay, still looking for a difference.)

Comment: Unsure whether this question is a true duplicate, but this other [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8630378/3545273) could help...

Comment: @Peter A. Schneider I am using the same gcc version under Linux.  You can catch the error copying the 2nd printf of displayArray2 to displayArray1.

Comment: Oh, now I understand. Thanks.

Comment: Just a remark: You are using Variable Length Arrays here. They are supported by gcc and Clang, but are optional in current C11 standard...

Comment: @SergeBallesta ... and they are also not part of any C++ standard, which may be the direction in which the OP is heading. (C++ has, of course, vectors for that.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following two ways to pass/print the matrix:

```
void display3DArray1(int rows, int cols1, int cols2, int *A) {
    int *a, i, j, k;
    printf("\n");
    for(i=0; i<rows; i++) {
        for(j=0; j<cols1; j++) {
            for(k=0; k<cols2; k++) {
                a= A+(i*cols1*cols2)+(j*cols2)+k;
                printf("%d, %p\n", *a, a);
            }
        }
    }
}

void display3DArray2(int A[DIM1][DIM2][DIM3]) {
    int i, j, k;
    printf("\n");
    for(i=0; i<DIM1; i++) {
        for(j=0; j<DIM2; j++) {
            for(k=0; k<DIM3; k++) {
                printf("%d, %p\n", A[i][j][k], &A[i][j][k]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The first method does not rely on the dimensions of the matrix; the second one does. As a result, the first one needs explicit address calculations (row *i*, col *j*, cell *k*).

Use calls respectively:

```
display3DArray1(DIM1, DIM2, DIM3, (int *)matrix3D);
display3DArray2(matrix3D);
```

Note the cast of the matrix to an int pointer.

In your code, you used parameter names to specify the dimensions of the matrix. In my C version, that is not legal; they must be constants.

Comment: @Serge Ballesta, could you please post an answer `display3DArray3` that shows the use of a VLA (I can't test it with my older version). Thx!

Comment: The published code *does* use VLAs as function arguments.

Comment: @Paul Ogilvie: `display3DArray3` runs exactly as it should. My intention is to use VLA. Otherwise I would need a function to every array. `FORTRAN` is much easier of doing that.

Comment: @PedroR. The traditional C way just uses a simple pointer to the first int as argument, together with the dimensions as extra parameters (which is required for VLAs as well). The function then accesses elements through manual multiplication with row and column sizes to compute offsets. Admittedly, indexing VLAs is better to read.

Comment: Pedro, please note that my first solution allows to pass _any_ 3D array with _any_ dimensions so you won't need a separate function for each array. But using VLAs is a more elegant solution. See Serge's solution.

Answer (score 2):

Just a complement to Paul Ogilvie's answer.

The correct usage of Variable Length Arrays would be:

```
void display3DArray3(int rows, int cols1, int cols2,int arr[][cols1][cols2]) {
    printf("\n");
    for(int i=0; i<rows; i++) {
        for(int j=0; j<cols1; j++) {
            for(int k=0; k<cols2; k++) {
                printf("*arr : %d adress: %p\n", arr[i][j][k], &arr[i][j][k]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @PaulOgilvie: This is not an answer by itself, but I could test this code. Feel free to use it in your answer and I will remove it (just ping me when done)

Comment: But this is exactly what the OP does in `display3DArray2`, if I don't miss anything, notation issues aside?

Comment: Serge, the first dimension is not specified and I understand it is variable (any number of rows, as lomg as all other dimensions are specified, the compiler can insert the code for the calculations). Correct?

Comment: Peter, the VLA spec in the function heading, yes, but then he goes off in the adderss calculations - in stead of just using `[..]`.

Comment: I see your point, but no addresses are calculated. For example, there are no multiplications, as opposed to the first function which uses only half a VLA. The elements are indeed accessed by proper indexing the various nested arrays, just using `*(p+i)` instead of `p[i]`.  The two are exactly equivalent.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie All the compiler needs to know for indexing is the element *size*. The innermost index only specifies the *number* of elements which in C is never checked anyway and hence can be omitted. The function must get it through a parameter (as it does).

Answer (score 1):

I was a bit puzzled, to be honest. The core issue is that the declaration of a function parameter like in `f(T arr[])` declares an incomplete type whose size is not known (neither at compile time nor at run time). Originally I thought empty square brackets in function parameter declarations simply declare a pointer — notation notwithstanding —, but that is not the case. The parameter still has array type, albeit *incomplete.*<sup>1</sup>

When you write

```
void display3DArray1(int rows, int cols1, int cols2,int (*arr)[][cols2])
```

you declare a *pointer* to such an incomplete type of unknown size. This pointer cannot be manipulated in all the usual ways; in particular, adding to it in order to jump to the next element is impossible because we don't know where the current element ends (and hence the next element starts). But you try that in

```
printf("*arr : %d adress: %p\n", *(*(*(arr+i)+j) + k), *(*(arr+i)+j) + k) ;
```

with the innermost `arr+1`. Just *dereferencing* it works, because the variable holds the address of the first element all right. This is what the print in the first function does:

```
 printf("*arr : %d adress: %p\n",*(*((*arr+i*cols1))+j*cols2+k),*((*arr+i*cols1))+j*cols2+k);
```

with `*arr`. The *element size*  of the incomplete array to which `arr` points is known (these elements are arrays of `cols2` ints), so that we can add to `*arr`,  even if we can't add to `arr`  proper.

For completeness: Why can you access `arr` that way in the second function? Well:

```
void display3DArray2(int rows, int cols1, int cols2,int arr[][cols1][cols2])
```

declares `arr` as an incomplete array type, true; but the size of its elements is well known: Those are cols1 x cols2 int matrices. The declaration just doesn't specify how many are there, but we can surely iterate them if we somehow know when to stop.

---

<sup><sub>1</sub></sup> <sub>Of course this array, like any other, "decays" to a pointer in most contexts, so that the missing type information doesn't matter. But it matters if we have pointers to them.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

I had trouble finding the correct syntax for dereferencing matrices of rank2 and rank3. The intent is to remove a level of indexing for faster execution. Here's some pseudo code that will get you started. This is more about getting the syntax right (MSVC 2019) than an example of working code.

```
int recurse(int n, unsigned char rank2[13][4], unsigned char rank3[13][4][13])
{
    if (n < 13)
    {
       unsigned char (*deRefRank1)[4] = &rank2[n]; // deref matrix rank 2 to rank 1
       unsigned char(*deRefRank2)[4][13] = &rank3[n]; // deref matrix rank 3 to 2
       // insert pre-recurse code here ... use (*deRefRank1)[] and (*deRefRank2)[][]
       if (recurse(n + 1, rank2[n], rank3[n])
           return -1;
       // insert post-recurse code here ...
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Your array indexing in the 'print' routines is invalid.  The declaration of 'matrix3D' implies that the type of that name is 'pointer to int'.  NOTE: Only one level of indirection there.  The indexing expressions have a bunch of '*'-s in front of terms; in C that means 'the item to the right of the '*' is a pointer which must be dereferenced to get to the value'.  That means you are in effect treating 'matrix3D' as 'pointer to (pointer to (pointer to int))' which is too many indirections.

Comment: Re " The declaration of 'matrix3D' implies that the type of that name is 'pointer to int'." No, it doesn't. It clearly declares a 3-dimensional array (or, which is equivalent, a one-dimensional array of 2-dimensional arrays; apply recursively).