# How does pointer arithmetic differ in case of 2D array when '&' operator is attached to the array name?

Tags: c

For the below code snippet , what type of rvalue is returned by expression array+1 and &array+1 ?

```
int main()
{
int array[2][3];
printf("%p  %p ", array+1, &array+1);
return 0;
}
```

I have already gone through below link but still my doubt is not cleared .

[2D array variable pointer confusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8630054/2d-array-variable-pointer-confusion/8630378?noredirect=1#comment73452030_8630378)

Comment: `array` evaluate => `int(*)[3]` so `+1` corresponds to the movement of `int[3]` (as `3*sizeof(int)`). `&array` evaluate => `int(*)[2][3]` so `+1` corresponds to the movement of `int[2][3]` (as `6*sizeof(int)`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- When `array` is used in an expression, it "decays" to a pointer of the first element.
- The first element of a 2D array `int[2][3]` is a 1D array `int[3]`.
- Therefore the expression `array+1` gives a pointer to such a 1D array.
- The expression `array+1` has type `int(*)[3]`, an array pointer to an array of 3 integers.
- When you do `+ 1` on any pointer, pointer arithmetic is invoked and you get "plus one pointed-at object", rather than "plus one byte/address".
- Thus `array+1` gives the second array of type `int[3]` in your 2D array.

---

- `&array` is different, it gives a pointer to the address of the array itself. A pointer to a 2D array, type `int(*)[2][3]`.
- If you do `&array + 1` you therefore do pointer arithmetic on objects that are 2D arrays and end up pointing "one 2D array outside the allocated array", which probably isn't meaningful.

Comment: I can't help but wonder about the last bullet. Computing the address of one past the end of an array is explicitly okay by the standard. But is a single variable considered an "array of 1" for `&var + 1` to be well defined?

Comment: @StoryTeller You can point one past the end of the array, but you may not de-reference the object there. As far as I know, the "one past the end" is allowed just to make constructs like this possible: `start=list; end=list+list.size(); for(i=start; i!=end; i++) { ...`

Comment: I know it's allowed and I know why (I do believe my comment starts with that). But while it may hold for `int a[1];` that calculating `a + 1` is okay, I'm not so certain it will be okay for `int a;` to calculate `&a + 1`. This is a pure language lawyer pondering.

Comment: @StoryTeller It is the same. 6.5.6/7 "For the purposes of these operators, a pointer to an object that is not an element of an
array behaves the same as a pointer to the first element of an array of length one with the type of the object as its element type."

Comment: Thank you! Trying to find something in the standard draft by doing a search on the word "array" is like looking for a needle in a haystack.

Comment: I understood your point but can you please explain why is it so , that array and &array behave differently although if we try printing them , they result in same address values ,how is it that in one case we get a different pointer and in another one , we get a different pointer

Comment: @stackuser The address of the 2D array is obviously the same as the address of the first 1D array in that 2D array. But if you do pointer arithmetic on them, you'll get different results, as explained in the answer.